# SQL Server query: Finding all entities within a given radius in a map with longitude and altitude coordinates

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to know how to write an SQL Server query that will return all entities (for example bus stations) within radius of 100 meters from a given location (for example: 53.55,-6.22 which is a GPS decimal coordinate).

Say that I have a table of bus station:

```
bus_station (station_id, station_location)
```

and I can represent the location as decimal data type or as a point data type.

```
SELECT b.station_id 
FROM bus_station b
WHERE b.station_location...   - how do I continue from here?
```

Comment: Use the Haversine formula, or better yet use a geo extension for SQL Server.

Comment: Check this article: [SQL Server Spatial Support: An Introduction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/isaac/2007/05/16/sql-server-spatial-support-an-introduction/) ;).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample against my ZipCode database

```
Declare @CurrentLat float =  41.744068    
Declare @CurrentLng float = -71.315024
Declare @Radius     float = 10000

Select *
 From (
        Select Distinct
               A.ZipCode
              ,A.CityName
              ,A.StateCode
              ,A.Lat
              ,A.Lng
              ,Meters = [dbo].[udf-Geo-Meters] (@CurrentLat,@CurrentLng,A.Lat,A.Lng)
         From  [Chinrus-Shared].[dbo].[ZipCodes] A
         Where CityType = 'D'
           and ZipType  = 'S'
           and A.Lat between @CurrentLat-1 and @CurrentLat+1    --<< Optional Depending on Size of Database
           and A.Lng between @CurrentLng-1 and @CurrentLng+1    --<< Optional Depending on Size of Database
      ) A
 Where Meters <= @Radius
 Order By Meters
```

Returns

[image]

The UDF to calc Meters

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[udf-Geo-Meters](@Lat1 FLOAT, @Lng1 FLOAT, @Lat2 FLOAT, @Lng2 FLOAT)
Returns Float as
Begin
    Return ACOS(SIN(PI()*@Lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@Lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@Lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@Lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@Lng2/180.0-PI()*@Lng1/180.0))*6371000
End
```